# Error in knn(trainDataX, validationDataX, trainingType, k = 3) : 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Tags: r, pca, knn

i am learning how to use R program language. Now i am learning the pca technique, the question was to train a model with the knn technique and to find out which is the accuracy value for the training model here is my code, actually i am not preety sure if what i've made till now is correct, anyway.

[image]

sorry for the .png for the code i just couldn't give to the code the format i wanted. Thanks for your time!

Comment: 1. Try `pca` process before split your data into training and validation. 2 Try `k=6` given your Type has 6 unique levels?

Comment: both of them are asked from the question

Comment: I tried k = 6 just to see what happens and it didn't work.